# ¿Cómo paso un valor precargado a Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

estoy trabajando con vuejs 2.0 y laravel 8, necesito que vue almacena en una variable el valor precargado de un input.

Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="number" v-model.number="num" value="{{$nota->promedio}}">
```

al colocar un `@{{num}}` me aparece vacío hasta que cambio el valor del input, entonces empieza a funcionar.

¿Cómo podría hacer para que por ejemplo me tomara el valor de `{{$nota->promedio}}` (donde `{{$nota->promedio}}` es una variable de un controlador de Laravel) un 60 por ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar el bind en la propiedad a modificar:

```
<input type="number" v-bind:value="$nota->promedio">
```

Y desde la vista al modelo sería con v-model:

```
<input type="number" v-model:value="$nota->promedio">
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola osea que tengo que usar 2 inputs y no solo 1 como tengo en el ejemplo?

Comment: no, el v-model funciona del modelo a la vista y de la vista al modelo, el v-bind solo del modelo a la vista, dicho de otra manera, si usas v-model lo que coloques en data se verá en el value del input y si se escribe un numero en el input se modificará la data, con v-bind lo que se coloque en data se verá en el input pero al escribir un número en el input no se modificará la data.Es como que si quieres solo mostrar usas v-bind, si quieres mostrar y que se pueda editar usas v-model

Comment: si, tal vez no me explique bien, de hecho necesito tener un valor pre-cargado, pero si es necesario modificarlo quiero modificarlo, ahora esa parte de lo que funciona en el modelo y en la vista no mucho lo interpreté ya que no he usado inputs en los modelos, solo en las vistas. puedo poner la linea de codigo de v-bind en el modelo?

Comment: Aumm no se entendió, a ver si tu tienes en la data de vue una propiedad llamada numero y quieres que al cargar la app se vea esa información en un input puedes indicarle al input v-bind:value="numero", eso hace que se vea en el input ese numero. Ahora si quieres que al ingresar un número en ese input (desde el navegador) se guarde ese dato en numero, entonces hay que cambiar de v-bind a v-model para que vue tome ese valor y automáticamente lo guarde en la propiedad numero.

Comment: Ah ya, pero siento que no es exactamente lo que necesito, porque lo que quiero es que el valor precargado lo mando desde un controlador así como lo mostré en el ejemplo {{$nota->promedio}} pero que pueda cambiarlo si yo quiero. será que se podría hacer algo así?

Comment: @MauEspaña como que nota->promedio viene de un controlador? no es una variable en tu vue? aclara todo eso en tu pregunta...

Comment: Ya hice la corrección, creo que por eso no nos entendíamos bien.

Comment: @zerocool osea que no hay una forma de hacerlo a cómo yo lo estoy trabajando?